# Error in ajax call post method is not supported in laravel 6.2 with php version 7.4.2

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, post, laravel-6.2

from this link i open update male bus schedule view with provided key.

```
<a href="{{ route('update male bus schedule',$key) }}" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding: 
6px;margin-top: 7px">Update</a>
```

here is the route.

```
Route::get('update male bus schedule/{key}', [
    'uses' => 'busScheduleController@returnMaleBusScheduleUpdateView',
    'as'   => 'update male bus schedule'
]);
```

it is controller for open update male bus schedule view

```
public function returnMaleBusScheduleUpdateView($key)
{
    $route = new Route();
    $nameData = $route->getAllRouteNames();
    $schedule = new BusSchedule();
    $getData = $schedule->getMaleBusScheduledetailByKey($key);
    return view('update male bus schedule', ['id' => $getData, 'key' => $key,'items'=>$nameData]);
}
```

now in update male bus schedule view i call ajax on button click.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="{{$id['id']}}" onclick="updateSchedule(this.id)">Update
</button>
```

here is the javascript function.

```
function updateSchedule(id) {
    var time = $('#time').val();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var busNo = $('#busNo').val();
    var timeCheck="false";
    busNo = busNo.trim();
    if (busNo != "") {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update male bus schedule value from controller",
            data: {
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                "name": name,
                "busNo": busNo,
                "time": time,
                "id" : id,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error:function (data) {
                alert(data);
                console.log(data);
            }

        });
    } else {
        alert("enter bus number.");
    }

}
```

here is the route for this ajax call.

```
Route::post('/update male bus schedule value from controller','busScheduleController@updateMaleBusScheduleById');
```

here is the controller.

```
  public function updateMaleBusScheduleById(Request $request)
    {
        return "true";
    }
```

but i get error

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

i get this error when i change view with

```
 <a href="{{ route('update male bus schedule',$key) }}" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding: 6px;margin-top: 7px">Update</a>.
```

Comment: You route is GET `Route::get('update male bus schedule/{key}',...`, your ajax call is POST `$.ajax({ type: "POST",` as the error indicates, methods should be same.

Comment: @user3532758 route is post and in ajax call method is also post.     Route::post('/update male bus schedule value from controller','busScheduleController@updateMaleBusScheduleById');

Answer (score 1):

Rename your route, never use spaces in your routes and make them logical.
`/malebusschedule/update` for example or even beter make it a PUT
or even `/male-bus-schedule/update`

Comment: removing spaces and change route to PUT also does not work. The problem occur when i change view with <a> html tag with key(provided data). I also mention this problem in question.